# WSAGetLastError

Tags: c#, asp.net, winapi

I am getting this error as

WSAGetLastError() returned 10061, Connection refused

can anyone please advise me the reason and where to look for the cause of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the WinSock API telling you that a connection to a remote server was refused. (The server is up, but isn't accepting connections on the port you want).  Who exactly tried to establish this connection is entirely application-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to connect to a server using a port number on which the server is not listening.

For example, you're trying to connect to port 80 but the remote machine isn't running a web server.

Answer (score 0):

For this error and any future Winsock errors, **[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa924071.aspx)** provides a comprehensive list of the error codes along with a brief description of what each means:

Answer (score 0):

As Dmitry correctly pointed out, this error happens when the remote machine exists, but is not accepting connections on the specified port. Alternatively it could be caused by firewall blocking the connection. I recommend using a tool like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to see the low-level TCP/IP packets that are exchanged.

Answer (score -1):

Server is not listening while client tries to make connection

Comment: It is a good practice to add answer only when it provides new informations relatively to the original question. Otherwise, it creates noise ;)